# How to get width in specified units (pt, ex, etc.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

In my script, i need to get width of an element in "ex" units (font width)

Is there any way to do this using JavaScript, jQuery ?

Comment: Element `width` / `font-size` in pixels? Edit: er, that's not quite right, `font-size` corresponds to `em`. For `ex`, you'll need to know the x-height of the particular font an calculate accordingly. You can probably determine this programmatically by adding a box with the same font and size, setting it to `width: 1ex` and calculating its pixel width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. jQuery uses the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties, which only return integer values. If the exact width you're looking for is specified in the stylesheet, you can probably use `element.css('width')` and get the intended result, but, otherwise, you'll have to either do some serious trickery to convert, or just deal with using pixels instead.